# Finding height of the largest div element and setting it for all div elements Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a div element that is looped through an array of objects using *ngFor. The height of a particular div is different from each other as each object contains different amounts of word count. I want to get the largest div element's height and set it as the div height so all div elements look the same. I am using Bootstrap 4.xx

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let food of foods">
  <div class="food-card">
     <h4>{{food.title}}</h4>
     <p>{{food.ingredients}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ingredients contain a lot of words in it and the word count varies from each food item.

Comment: While you can absolutely do this with JavaScript and usually had to be, this can be achieved via Flexbox. Check out resources like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewChildren to get the elements, and in ngAfterViewInit, get the size

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let food of foods">
  <div #foodcard class="food-card">
     <h4>{{food.title}}</h4>
     <p>{{food.ingredients}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

@ViewChildren('foodcard') foodCards:QueryList<ElementRef>
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   let maxHeight=0
   this.foodCards.forEach(x=>{
     const height=x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().height
     if (heigth>maxHeight)
        maxHeight=height
   })

}
```

Anyway, if your aim is set the same height check [card-deck](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/#card-decks)