# Check for the width of div with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am working on a project where we have a requirement where I need to check whether total width of dynamically generated divs using `*ngFor` is bigger than the parent element or not. HTML looks as below

```
<div class="emp_parent">
     <div class="emp_child" *ngFor="let emp of data;let i = index;">
       // some code goes here
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here as you see in the above section I need to check total width of *emp_child* and also need to check whether it is going beyond *emp_parent* or not. Based on that I need to make other conditions. I am trying but I am not able to get the total width of dynamically generated *emp_child*'s width. Any solution for this ?

Comment: Do you really need the calculated length? Or is it just a matter of adjusting the display in response to the length? In that case, it could be handled by some responsive CSS.

Comment: I need to check whether total width is more than parent width or not. So based on that I will put condition for other thing. So yes length is required. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Use ViewChildren, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227026/finding-height-of-the-largest-div-element-and-setting-it-for-all-div-elements-an/62230866#62230866 (in the SO it showed how get the max height, similar way you can calculate total width)